# Secondary Routing Priority favors Web-to-Case over Email-to-Case?

Tags: case, service-cloud-console, queue, assignment-rules, omnichannel

We have "secondary routing priority" activated.
We set a priority status on a case record to either "low" or "high".
When we have **the same priority** on a web and email case, the web will be **pushed first**, even if the **web case is younger**.
With "secondary routing priority" activated, web cases seem to be always pushed first, no matter what.

Everything else seems to be the same, same queue, etc.

Does anyone know why that is? Does anyone have a clue? Are we missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether both Web and Email cases are going in the same queue or in different queues, if in same queue then secondary prioritization should work as per the configurations. If not then check the queue priority, if web cases queue is higher priority, then those cases will be delivered first.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/177847)